# If $\, \gcd(a,b)=d\,$ then prove that $\,\gcd(a/d, b/d)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $\,\gcd(a,b)=d,$ then how can I prove that $\gcd(a/d,b/d)=1$

Comment: Isn't this obvious? Since $\gcd(a,b)=d$, we can write $a=dp$ and $b=dq$ for coprime integers $p,q$ (since if $p,q$ aren't coprime, it'll lead to a contradiction that $\gcd(a,b)=1$). So, you have, $$\gcd(p,q)=1\implies\gcd(a/d,b/d)=1$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It follows from Bézout's identity.
Since $d=\mbox{gcd}(a,b)$, then $d$ is the smallest positive integer which can be written in the from $$d=ap+bq$$ for some $p,q\in\mathbb Z $;
therefore, dividing by $1$ we have $$1=\frac ad p+\frac bdq .$$